# Spring Boot AWS Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, localstack

I have a problem about getting specified secret from AWS Secret Manager in my Spring Boot Example.

I think localstack is useful for the process.

Here is the localstack code snippet defined in docker-compose.

```
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=test
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=test
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-3
    ports:
      - '4566-4597:4566-4597'
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
```

After I ran setup-aws.sh, I tried to run the Spring Boot example.

I couldn't get secret value?

How can I fix it?

Here is the application.properties file

```
cloud.aws.end-point.uri=http://s3.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/
cloud.aws.secrets-manager.end-point.uri=http://localhost:4566  -> secretManagerUrl

s3.bucket.base.url=http://bucketnameproject.s3.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/
```

Here is the init method of AWSConfiguration file

```
public void init() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String secretName = "aws/secret";
        String region = "eu-west-3";

        AWSSecretsManager client = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(secretManagerUrl, region))
                .build();

        String secret;
        GetSecretValueRequest getSecretValueRequest = new GetSecretValueRequest()
                .withSecretId(secretName);
        GetSecretValueResult getSecretValueResult = null;

        getSecretValueResult = client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest);

        secret = getSecretValueResult.getSecretString(); // HERE IS THE ERROR LOCATION

        ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, String>  read = m.readValue(secret, Map.class);
        read.forEach((key, value) -> {
            secretCache.put("accessKey", key);
            secretCache.put("secretKey", value);
        });
    }
```

Here is the setup-aws.sh shown below.

```
aws configure set aws_access_key_id "test"
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key "test"
aws configure set default.region eu-west-3


aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 secretsmanager create-secret --name aws/secret --secret-string '{"my_uname":"username","my_pwd":"password"}'

aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566  s3api create-bucket \
              --bucket bucketnameproject \
              --region eu-west-1 \
              --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=eu-west-3
```

Here is the output of sh file

```
{
    "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:000000000000:secret:aws/secret-A
dRTaw",
    "Name": "aws/secret",
    "VersionId": "ce0e8536-565a-4791-9259-8272d46e04be"
}
```

Here is the output of `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566/ secretsmanager list-secrets`

```
    "SecretList": [
        {
            "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:000000000000:secret:aws/secret-ScYdQq",
            "Name": "aws/secret",
            "LastChangedDate": "2022-10-18T00:18:02.283609+03:00",
            "SecretVersionsToStages": {
                "eca973d8-c502-4c74-a646-8e412cd66973": [
                    "AWSCURRENT"
                ]
            },
            "CreatedDate": "2022-10-18T00:18:02.283609+03:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the error shown below.

```
com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.model.ResourceNotFoundException: Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret. (Service: AWSSecretsManager; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 55AQCW3AFW5RK39GQZGXAK6MVHG80K7W6SGYTUE5MTJ5X5TMLEMB; Proxy: null)
```

Comment: There's really nothing SpringBoot specific here. This is just some Java code calling the AWS SDK for Java. If it can't find the secret, then either the name you are giving it is incorrect, or the region is incorrect, or the access key/secret key you gave it is for a different account.

Comment: So you're using something like localstack to do this, instead of actually using AWS? What's the value of `secretManagerUrl` in the Java code? Also, did you notice the region you show in the code is not the region shown in the error message?

Comment: @MarkB I forgot to add localstack properties. I added all them.

Comment: You still haven't shown what value the `secretManagerUrl` variable in the Java code contains. And you don't appear to be setting the SecretsManager URL in the application.properties file either.

Comment: @MarkB `@Value("${cloud.aws.secrets-manager.end-point.uri}")
    private String secretManagerUrl;`

Comment: @MarkB I still couldn't fix the issue.

Comment: @MarkB I have another issue regarding aws not running with localstack in docker-compose. Can you help me ? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363198/cannot-run-sh-file-regarding-aws-configure-in-localstack-in-docker-compose-yml

Comment: I am having the same issue with .Net, any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand what is aws account secret  and aws Secrets Manager:

- aws account secret is used for client (java, shell, etc) authentication
- aws Secrets Manager is a online service to centralize some secret of your app like database_host, database_password, some_api_key, etc

To finf the error, follow these steps

### retrieve the value

If your secret was created correctly, try to retrieve it:

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id account-player1
```

If you can't by shell, neither can the java.

### id should contain the arn

According to the some posts, the secret name should be the entire ARN:

So instead **"aws/secret"** of `String secretName = "aws/secret";` use

```
arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:000000000000:secret:aws/secret-A
dRTaw
```

### docs and posts

- [AWS Secrets Manager can’t find the specified secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57821886/aws-secrets-manager-can-t-find-the-specified-secret)
- https://www.bitovi.com/blog/aws-secrets-manager-devops
- https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/2.3.0/secrets-backends/aws-secrets-manager.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html

Comment: I also defined `arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:000000000000:secret:aws/secret-A
dRTaw``but I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you validate the value retrieve with the shell? Also the arn is not defined by the user. You define only the key, the arn is created by aws

Comment: I still couldn't fix it.

Comment: Did you validate the value retrieve with the shell?

Comment: I have another issue regarding aws not running with localstack in docker-compose. Can you help me ? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363198/cannot-run-sh-file-regarding-aws-configure-in-localstack-in-docker-compose-yml

Comment: If this was useful, click on the upper arrow and mark as solved

Comment: I tried to clean and build the project and check the environmental variables in the system and then define some of the variables. Next, it works. Can you look through my another issue if possible?

Comment: I have another issue regarding aws not running with localstack in docker-compose. Can you help me ? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363198/cannot-run-sh-file-regarding-aws-configure-in-localstack-in-docker-compose-yml